# Can't access my AWS hosted database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am having a huge issue with accessing my AWS database from within the php code for a site i am building.  I have tried many different connection methods, and all seem to give an error that says

```
    Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '(the endpoint of my hosted DB)' (111)
```

I've looked up error 111, but I can not seem to understand why it applies to me in this scenario.  I can access my database from any computer, using the same information I'm using here to try to connect.  I'm starting to think it's the host I'm using for my site that's the problem.  I'm using the free biz.nf host just for testing, but I'm not sure my site host really should have any effect on the php inside my site. Here's my connect statement

```
    $mysql_host="DB endpoint";
    $mysql_user="myusername";
    $mysql_pass="mypassword";
    $my_db="myDBname";

    $con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to update your security group and route tables for your subnets to allow the host on biz.nf to access the RDS instance.

Check your RDS dashboard for the given instance, and examine the settings on your security group and subnets.

Comment: So I had a problem before this where I couldn't connect to the database on any computer outside of my own laptop.  I fixed that by adjusting the security group on RDS and specifying the source for inbound traffic as  
0.0.0.0/0 so that any connection from any IP address could be made.  Do you think doing that should have solved the problem you are describing?

Comment: Fixing the security group is part of the solution. But you also have to fix the route tables in the subnets. BTW, opening up the security group to allow access from any host (0.0.0.0/0) is dangerous.

Comment: I know it's dangerous, but this is a just a site for a school project, so there is no sensitive information.  Now, when you say fix the route tables, what exactly do I modify? Do I have to allow certain IP address in there as well?

Comment: That's correct. Either allow specific IP addresses, or a range. Both must be expressed in CIDR notation.

Comment: Ok, so I checked the route tables, and it seems like it was already set up to allow traffic from all IP addresses.  Is there any other table I need to modify?

Comment: If the security group is set up to allow the right protocol (MySQL?) from the right addresses, and the route tables allow traffic from those addresses, then you don't have a network security problem. You might check to make sure you're using the correct user/password, and that the user is properly configured in the database.

Comment: Man, I've checked the user credientials a million times already.  I took it to my professor and he couldnt see the problem either.  He, and another one of my classmates said that biz.nf is probably the culprit and I should try hosting both the database and the site on azure.  Thanks for your time and effort, though!

Comment: No sweat. I hope it works out! Post your answer here for others.